# How to make the last column full-width

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following section with `.col-md-8` and `.col-md-4` in the general Bootstrap 3 `.container` (not a fluid).
I need the right column to reach with its background to the display's edge. How can I solve my problem? Thanks.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class="home--hero">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12 npl">
                    <div class="hero--wrapper">
                        <h1>Title</h1>
                        <ul class="banner-list banner-list-black">
                            <li><span>Lorem</span></li>
                            <li><span>Ipsum</span></li>
                            <li><span>Dolor</span></li>
                        </ul>    
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                      Lorem Ipsum
                    </div>
            </div><!-- content -->
        </div><!-- row -->
    </div><!-- container -->
</section><!-- home hero section -->
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the problem.  you've flagged the previous cell as `col-xs-12` so anything else will **always** wrap to the left.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I've attached a screenshot with a brief explanation.

Comment: @Morgari will that white box always will be positioned at the corner of screen, even after scroll?

Comment: Yes, I'd like this box to be there after scroll. This is a hero section of my website. Features on the left Hero side (col-md-8) and the sign-up form on the right side (col-md-4). It shouldn't be 'fixed'. But I have no clue how to do it in such a way.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,
remove col-md-4 class, make its `position:absolute` and `right:0`

Make **.home--hero** `position:relative`

```css
.home--hero{
position:relative;
}

.right-side{
position:absolute;
background:red;
right:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class="home--hero">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            
                <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12 npl">
                    <div class="hero--wrapper">
                        <h1>Title</h1>
                        <ul class="banner-list banner-list-black">
                            <li><span>Lorem</span></li>
                            <li><span>Ipsum</span></li>
                            <li><span>Dolor</span></li>
                        </ul>    
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="right-side">
                      Lorem Ipsum
                    </div>

        </div><!-- row -->
    </div><!-- container -->
</section><!-- home hero section -->
```

Comment: One moment, please, checking atm

Comment: Thanks, this solution is fine. Unfortunately, content doesn't going after the col-md-8 and it sticks to the right edge.